# Querying outside of a transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, transactions

I've got a Trigger (yes I know, yuk) that needs to check that a bunch of updates to another table has finished before sending out a notification.

I can't avoid having to do this in a Trigger like this due to the source database being 3rd party and being designed badly in my opinion.

The problem being is that the trigger has its own transaction and does not detect any changes to the table, as they are happening outside of it.

Is there any way to get around this?

In the code below, I'm getting values from the metricvalue table and creating xml with it. currently it doesn't get all the available records as the trigger is being called before all the metrics are written (there is no way to avoid this unfortunately). I was hoping to put in a .5 sec pause and then do the query, but because of the transaction problem this doesn't work.

code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER  [dbo].[STR_MetricStatusChange]
ON [dbo].[MetricStatus]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @Runid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
DECLARE @run_number INT;
DECLARE @sample_number INT;
DECLARE @primary_step INT;
DECLARE @secondary_step int;
DECLARE @secondary_step_maths_done int;
DECLARE @old_secondary_step_maths_done int;
DECLARE @primary_step_maths_done int;
DECLARE @old_primary_step_maths_done int;


DECLARE @Message nvarchar(MAX);

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED


-- Get the fields we need from the current MetricStatus record
--
SELECT @Runid = i.runid,
       @run_number = r.Run_Number,
       @sample_number = i.sample_number,
       @primary_step = i.primary_step,
       @secondary_step_maths_done = i.secondary_step_maths_done,
       @primary_step_maths_done = i.primary_step_maths_done
FROM INSERTED i
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Runs r ON r.Run_id = i.runid  


-- Standard Metrics secondary step notification to Notification Queue
--
SELECT @Message = (SELECT (SELECT 0 AS MessageType FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE ),
                          (SELECT  @Runid AS RunId, @run_number AS RunNumber, @sample_number AS SampleNumber, @primary_step AS PrimaryStep, @secondary_step AS SecondaryStep, GETDATE() AS [TimeStamp] FOR XML PATH('Details'), TYPE),
                          (SELECT 
                                  (SELECT mv.MetricValue_MetricId AS '@MetricId',
                                          mv.MetricValue_Value AS Value
                                   FROM dbo.MetricValues mv
                                   WHERE MetricValue_RunId = @Runid and MetricValue_SampleNumber = @sample_number
                                   for XML PATH('Metric'), TYPE)
                           FOR XML PATH('Metrics'),TYPE)
                   FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('Notification'))

-- Standard Metrics secondary step notification to Maths Engine Queue
--
EXEC dbo.usp_SendNotification @Message, 'MathsEngine';




END
```

Comment: oops sorry, SQL Server 2012

Comment: can you give some sample code of the situation?